# Microsoft Graph v1 webhook notifications are not being sent

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-graph-api

I have a weird issue with microsoft graph api v1.

I am trying to setup a subscription, so that I get webhook notification after a new outlook email arrives.

```
$body = [
    "changeType" => "created,updated",
    "notificationUrl" => route('api.outlook.push'),
    "resource" => "me/messages",
    "expirationDateTime" => now()->addMinutes(self::SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRATION_MINUTES),
];

$response = null;
try {
    $response = $this->service->createRequest('POST', '/subscriptions')
    ->attachBody(json_encode($body))
    ->setReturnType(Subscription::class)
    ->execute();
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    logger()->info('outlook subscription exception', ['message' => $exception->getMessage()]);
}
```

This seems to be working correctly as microsoft is sending a notification to specified url with verification code, that I'm returning and the message says that subscription was created. The issue is that even though it was set up properly - I am not getting a single one webhook. Did any of you guys had this issue and manage to fix it?